# Closing bootstrap modal with animate.css

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal, animate.css

I use a lot of modals on my current project. I'm using the Animated.css library for animations. - The problem is that I want to use a animation when the modal close. E.g: open modal = flipInX / closing modal = flipOutX

I've seen a lot of these questions, but I can't get it to work for me. I want the effect to work on all of my modals, not just one specific.

```
 <div class="modal animated flipInX fade modal-fullscreen" id="info" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="d01" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid">


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.modal {
    transiton: opacity 2s;
}

.modal-close {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

you can add the class to do the animation when the user close modal.

```
getElementById('btn-close-modal').classList.add('modal-close')
```

thus, the modal will assume 0 of aptitude with the animation defined in the modal-close class